# Sinatra: Array into HTML table

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am new to Sinatra.

I work currently on a project that is supposed to use a array,

*for example:* `ary = ['a','b','c']`

to covert it into an HTML table (possible using an .erb file).

The table should have a single column with as many rows, as there are strings (dynamic).

*for example:*

- a
- b
- c
- (any other item of the array)

I don't really have a clue how to do that and I tried code from similar projects, that didn't work. I hope its even possible to do.

Comment: As a side note, what you describe should definitely be be a ul / li instead of a table with a single column : http://jsfiddle.net/pjambet/XTexy/

Comment: Ya, thats true, but i think i am gonna use the table for some other things too. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the controller do

```
get '/something' do
  @ary = ['a','b','c']
  erb :'something'
end
```

In the view named something you can do

```
<table>
<% @ary.each do |elem| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= elem %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```